# Mongoose schemas cast error when adding a new category

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas, one collection and another category. A collection has many category and a category can have many collection items.

I'm looking to create a filter later on down the line.

category schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

let categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  collections: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Collection' }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('category', categorySchema)
```

collection schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

let collectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  categories: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories',
    required: true
  }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('collection', collectionSchema)
```

truncated this to keep it relevant.

I'm not looking to populate the references yet as I'm only doing the backend for now, so I'm only rendering JSON for now.

I can create multiple category

[image]

and I can create a collection with a category as a collection must have at least one category

[image]

I can edit a collection and add a new category

[image]

However, sometimes I seem to get the following error

[image]

I'm not sure why maybe the database hasn't updated in the app, I am using nodemon so I'm not really sure what the issue could be here.

Comment: Categories have to be valid ObjectIds, like this:
`categories: ['5db06d6fe1a3d0001734d6c5', '5db06dd9e1a3d0001734d6c6']` if you want to use values other the ObjectIds you should check out virtual populate https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett Would it be possible to give a code example? I'm still getting used to mongoose and mongodb. So it would really help. Thanks.

Comment: you should check your naming conventions. in collection collections: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Collections' }]

Comment: @nightcode see answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const CollectionSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
  categoryName: String
});

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

CollectionSchema.virtual('category', {
  ref: 'Category', // The model to use
  localField: 'name', // Find people where `localField`
  foreignField: 'categoryName', // is equal to `foreignField`
  // If `justOne` is true, 'members' will be a single doc as opposed to
  // an array. `justOne` is false by default.
  justOne: false,
  options: { sort: { name: -1 }, limit: 5 } //you can add options as well
});

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
const Collection = mongoose.model('Collection', CollectionSchema);

Collection.find({}).populate('category').exec(function(error, categories) {
  /* `categories.members` is now an array of instances of `Category` */
});
```

This [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) has additional Information